# VBA Parameter Error

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have been fiddling with this code for a few hours now and I can't get rid of the compile error.

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

''more code

objWord.Selection.TypeText (FDS.Cells(2, 8).Value)

objWord.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove (error occurs here)

ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=objWord.Selection.Range, Entry:=("Device")
objWord.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine

''more code
```

(I left out a lot of code since the module is huge)

What I want the code to do in the end is look in a specific excel cell and take that value and place it in the currently open word document. Then that value has to be selected and given a marking and then going to the end of the line.

I have tried all solutions that I know of and changing `Extend:=wdMove` to `Extend:=wdExtend` but nothing seems to work.

The only way I can get rid of the error is removing `Unit:=wdLine`. But this also makes sure it doesn't select the Value anymore.

Im hopeless at this point. So I will take any help.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Which error are you getting? Are you running this in Word or Excel?  Looks like you're mixing commands from both?

Comment: If you're using Word methods from Excel, have you added the Word obect library?

Comment: Well, after having a long hard look at the code I'll have to say I haven't got a clue.  It doesn't look like the code has a whole lot to do with the question though.  One thing that jumps out is that the code is in Excel as you create the Word application using late binding, but then use `wdMove` and `wdLine` which Excel won't understand.

Comment: @ashleedawg Error 4120, Running in Excel, I'm using excel to do some things in word yes.

Comment: Trying using `5` instead of `wdLine` and `0` in place of `wdMove`.

Comment: Yes, the Word commands are very specific to Word. The same as you can't use Worksheets in Word as the document doesn't have them.  To find the numerical equivalent you can open the Word VBE and enter the text in the Immediate window: `?wdLine` will return 5 in Word.

Comment: Ashleedawg hit it on the head: you don't have a reference (Tools/Reference) to the Word library, so you can't use the `wd` enumerations - you'll need to use their Long integer equivalent values, as Darren suggested. Just putting `xl` in there is of no help.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook THANK YOU sooo much!

Comment: Or you can set a reference to Word using Tools/Reference that @CindyMeister suggests.  Intellisense & all that becomes available then, but it falls over if someone is using a different version of Word.

Comment: Since more people are going to use this I'm sticking with the numerical ones. But I appreciate the help!

Comment: "Error 4120, Running in Excel", contradicts the notion of a **compile** error. Code that can't be *compiled*, will not *run*. If the code *runs*, then `Option Explicit` is missing - add it, and thank yourself later.

Comment: `Option Explicit` is already present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Trying using 5 instead of wdLine and 0 in place of wdMove. – Darren Bartrup-Cook

If you don't have a reference to the Microsoft Word type library, `wdLine` and `wdMove` are undefined.

If `Option Explicit` isn't specified at the top of the module, then they become *undeclared variables* with a default type of `Variant`, and since they're passed as arguments to members that expect enum values, they'll be passed as `0` - which may or may not be a valid value for the invoked member, and may or may not work as intended.

If `Option Explicit` is specified at the top of the module, the code doesn't compile, and the VBE highlights `wdLine` and `wdMove` as undeclared identifiers.

> Since more people are going to use this I'm sticking with the numerical ones. But I appreciate the help! – MateoVD

The best solution (assuming you're keeping the MS Word reference late-bound) is to maintain the readability of `wdLine` and `wdMove` values. Inlining their respective underlying integer value will work, but then you have `5` and `0` and no idea whatsoever about what these values mean: these are known as **magic numbers**, and they're a great source of hard-to-debug issues.

Declare the constants yourself. `wdLine` and `wdMove` are members of the [`WdUnits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdunits-enumeration-word) and [`WdMovementType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237814(v=office.12).aspx) enumerations, respectively.

You can define these enums yourself, at the top of any module - I'd recommend defining them in their own standard/procedural module (.bas), so that these values are accessible from anywhere in your code (they wouldn't be, if you defined them in e.g. a `Worksheet` class module):

```
'Module: WordConsts
'@Folder("Microsoft Word Constants")
Option Explicit

Public Enum WdUnits
    wdCell = 12
    wdCharacter = 1
    wdCharacterFormatting = 13
    wdColumn = 9
    wdItem = 16
    wdLine = 5
    wdParagraph = 4
    wdParagraphFormatting = 14
    wdRow = 10
    wdScreen = 7
    wdSection = 8
    wdSentence = 3
    wdStory = 6
    wdTable = 15
    wdWindow = 11
    wdWord = 2
End Enum

Public Enum WdMovementType
    wdMove = 0
    wdExtend = 1
End Enum
```

And now you can keep your code as-is, and use `wdMove` and `wdLine` and any other possible legal values, without having to dig them and their underlying values up online.

If you then add a reference to the Microsoft Word type library, the constants defined in your `WordConsts` module will take precedence over the same-name identifiers defined in the type library: this is called *shadowing*, or *hiding* - anything defined in your VBA project will always have higher precedence in identifier resolution.

---

TL;DR: Write code that *says what it does*, and *does what it says*. Magic numbers don't say anything - avoid them. If a number means something, give it a meaningful name. When a name exists for that value, use it.

Comment: Thank you for your explenation. Most of this is not new to me. But the magic number thing was. I get that it is better to not use them. But in this case its the best solution (for me). To not make it unclear I added comments behind the lines that say that `5` and `0` are equivalents of `wdLine` and `wdMove`. I will surely bookmark your Answer for future projects. It's very helpfull.